# Using exception handling if input is integer and between 0-9 in c#

Tags: c#, exception

This is my code so far to check if input is integer. I also want to check if integer is between 0-9. How do I do that?

```
        int selectionInput = 0;
        bool validInput = false;

        while (validInput == false)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("{0,30}", "Make a Selection >> ");
                selectionInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                validInput = true;   
            } 
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice - please select from 0 - 9");
            }

        }

       console.readline();
```

Comment: You could use `int.TryParse` and not use exception handling at all (probably better), or you could throw an exception if the value is less than 0 or greater than 9.  `throw new ApplicationException("bogus");`

Answer (score 0):

```
selectionInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
If(selectionInput >= 0 && selectionInput <= 9)
  validInput = true;
else
  validInput = false;
```

or

```
selectionInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
validInput = (selectionInput >= 0 && selectionInput <= 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

To put what zzxyz suggests in the comments (using `int.TryParse()`):

```
int selectionInput = 0;
bool validInput = false;

while (validInput == false)
{
    try
    {
        Console.Write("{0,30}", "Make a Selection >> ");
        validInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out selectionInput);
        if (validInput && (selectionInput < 0 || selectionInput > 9))
            validInput = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice - please select from 0 - 9");
    }

}
```

The `if` statement checks first if the input is a valid integer (see [int.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)) and then if its a valid integer and not in the range 0 to 9, it sets `validInput` to false.

If its not a valid integer in the first place, validInput is already false, and the `if` statement won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
int selectionInput = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("{0,30}", "Make a Selection >> ");
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out selectionInput);

            if (selectionInput > 10 || selectionInput < 1)
                Console.WriteLine("Please input numbers between 1 to 10");

        } while (selectionInput > 10 || selectionInput < 1);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Basically you do **try catch statement** when you are catching an error and not making a condition that if that condition fails, you do catch in on error block.

Usually try-catch error are good for error logs or you are really expecting an error on your code. `Error` is different from `if-else condition/flow control`.